# Absence of topological phases in quantum gravity and the BFSS matrix model of $M$-theory

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, quantum-gravity, string-theory-landscape

McNamara and Vafa have recently conjectured in their paper [Cobordism Classes and the Swampland](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.10355) that any vacua in string theory can be reached from any other one (possibly by a process that require an infinite amount of action) i.e. the cobordism class of string theory is trivial.

The motivations for the new swampland conjeture are the statement of uniqueness of quantum gravity (the moduli space of string theory is connected), the fact that in string theory every parameter is the VeV of a dynamical field that can be varied to reach any other of its configurations; and finally, the "completness of the spectrum" and "the absence of global charges" swampland criteria that eliminate any potential topological defect/global charge whose conservation potentially serve as a topological obstruction (a non-trivial cobordism class) to reach any configuration from any other given one.

An interesting consequence of the latter is stated in the minute 20:45 of the talk [On Uniqueness of Quantum Gravity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_iNfgUSemk).
**"There are no interesting interesting topological phases in a quantum theory of gravity because the moduli of a specific vacua can not be freezed in a consistent gravitational theory"**.

Now consider the Motl-Susskind interpretation of the finite $N$ BFSS matrix model as $M$-theory with the light-like direction $x^{-}=(x^{0} + x^{10})/\sqrt{2}$ compatified on a circle of radius $R$. What intrigues me is that even though the BFSS model correctly describes M-theory, all other ten dimensional string theories (or its compactifications) seem to be inaccessible by the BFSS model precisely because the moduli are frozen. I mean, in a manifestly Lorentz-covariant (non-light-cone-gauge) definition of perturbative string theory, we are able to "change the background" by adding exactly marginal operators to the worldsheet measure. But the story with the BFSS model is rather different, states with  $p^{-}=0$ (where $p^{-}$ is the complementary momentum coordinate to $x^{-}$) have trivial $U(0)$ Hilbert space and they are the only candidates to be the analogues of marginal operators (because marginal operators have $p^{-}=0$ in the light-cone definition of string theory); then it is not obvious (at least to my ignorance) how any of the other ten dimensional stringy vacua can be reached from the BFSS model; the problem looks to be exactly that BFSS states with $p^{-}=0$ "appear to be frozen", in apparent contradition with the statement of connectivity of the string theory moduli space.

A simple way to bypass the latter argument is to compactify $M$-theory on $T^{k}$ with $k>5$ to make some truly exceptional U-duality groups manifest and connect in that way with other superselection sectors of string theory, unfortunately the latter does not work because the Sen-Seiberg derivation of the matrix model for M-theory compactified on $T^{k}$ precisely brokes down at $k>5$. It is not clear to me that this is "just a technicality" and not a fundamental problem.

It´s worth to mention that I don't believe that the recent Vafa-McNamara arguments are absolutely needed to ask this question concerning the BFSS model. It is just that this is the first time I see the statement of "string theory moduli space connectivity" stated with such degree of clarity (besides [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9504145)).

**My questions:**

1. How to reconcile the Vafa-McNamara statement of dynamical moduli space connectivity of string/M-theory with the apparent fact that there are ten dimensional string theories that can not be obtained by varying some BFSS model moduli?
2. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?
3. Maybe the Vafa-McNamara arguments does not hold for the BFFS model of $M$-theory?

**Reference:** Luboš Motl [Feynman sum over Young diagrams (discrete histories)](https://motls.blogspot.com/2015/08/feynman-sum-over-young-diagrams.html)

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read or help me.